# Show the bounty notice/reason on hover instead of "this question has an open bounty worth x reputation"

Tags: feature-request, bounties, tooltips

There are different reasons for a bounty including "to award to an existing answer". In some other case, the person is looking for updated answer.

When saw a bounty in the featured tab, The title shows this question has an open bounty worth

> [image]

Instead if it shows the reason to put the bounty/ the notice, then it will be easy to decide whether we should open the question or not.

This will be helpful in all SE sites but since SO has large number of questions with bounty (At present, it is 399), it will be very much helpful in SO.

> [image]

So, it will look like

> [image]

Comment: Eh, I get you want better information, but a title is supposed to be used to explain "what is this?" Providing the reason for a bounty does not explain to a user what the blue box with a number in it means. The current title accurately explains "this blue box means it has an open bounty worth this much reputation."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comment by animuson, I think that this will be good for noobs.

So, I created a User Script to do the job.

At present, it works only for Stack Overflow.

The post in StackApps

[Bounty Notice Viewer - View the notice from Home page](https://stackapps.com/q/7452/44782)