# HTML Element Parsed differently in SE Sites

Tags: support, design

With reference to this question [Show the bounty notice/reason on hover instead of "this question has an open bounty worth x reputation"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296956/228134), I created a User Script which works only for Stack Overflow yesterday.

Today, I tried to add support to other SE sites but the script is breaking.

I worked on it and found out the issue but it is strange.

#### The Issue

In Stack Overflow, the `<h3>` element contains the Link to question is parsed as `HTML Element`.

[image]

But in Some other SE sites Including MSE, the `<h3>` parsed as `Text Node` and that is the reason for the `children` prevents from running.

[image]

In such case, what should I do in order to make the script a stable behaviour?

Is this a browser behaviour or an SE issue?

I can't see this issue in SO anyway.

> Chrome/58.0.3029.110

Comment: The `#text` element is just the intervening whitespace in the HTML source. Use `nextElementSibling` to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try that and let you know.

Comment: But still the problem is I am getting either `html element` or `textnode`. Not a stable behaviour. Is this a problem with my browser or SE?

Comment: It's stable, and that's the way the standards say to do it. It's just that in one case there's whitespace in the source, and in another case there isn't. It has no other effect.